# Best way to pass variable from python to C in real time

Tags: python, c, variables, media-player

I have a media player I've created in C, and its running along side a server I have in Python. The server accepts commands to modify a play list that resides in an SQLite database.

Once the python code updates the DB (This happens in the background while the media player is playing) it needs to let the player know a new playlist is in the DB so it can start playing the new files.

I was going to set a flag in the DB, and the player can constantly poll this flag, but I don't think this is the best way. All the options I can think of involve the media player constantly checking for something.

What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: [Signals](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html)?

Comment: @JakobBowyer: redis is hardly an appropriate piece of software to bundle with a media player just to transmit a little data from program A to program B, especially when there are much simpler methods.

Comment: dbus might be an alternative if you're using linux

Comment: @DietrichEpp I bundled twisted into my IDE I wrote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways you can do that:

1. Signals - send SIGUSR1 signal to player from Python.
2. Sockets - player listens on some port and Python sends some data on that port (UDP will be easiest in that case).
3. Fifo - there is `mkfifo` on Linux machines. Files created that way works similar to sockets.

I would recommend UDP sockets. It's easy, fast and more elegant than signals. Python code would be something about 3 lines of code.

Example Python code:

```
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9999))
sock.sendall('update')
sock.close()
```

Example C UDP server:
http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/udp-server.c

Comment: +1, it would be nice to  mention http://redis.io/topics/pubsub as well, it is also elegant way for message passing and you have bonus `redis` :)

Comment: `redis` makes sens if you have more complicated situation (ie. multiple players and multiple Python scripts) or you are already using `redis` to something else. In this case its overshooting, because its much more complicated to implement (proper configuration for `redis` can take more time than full UPD or signals implementation) and harder to maintain. Also this looks like Desktop solution, so you probably don't want to setup `redis` (author don't even want to setup DB server and is using SQLite instead).

Comment: Unix domain sockets might be marginally easier to work with than UDP sockets, since you don't have to pick a port number and they have guaranteed delivery.  The code would be almost the same.

Comment: @DietrichEpp unix sockets: pros - faster, no need to pick port, guaranteed delivery, cons - you have to handle situation when player is not running, you need directory to put socket in (/tmp is good but not perfect), you must manage permissions, no easy way to move to Windows, you have to create socket before Python tries to connect. IMO: UDP is easier for beginner, unix socket is more elegant.

Comment: It will only be running on Debian ARM.
Can you give example/link of unix socket method?

Comment: And with the sockets, is it fine leaving the socket open indefinitely? ie for months.
Or do they close down after a connection is made then Ill have to open up another one straight away that would be waiting months before it gets a new msg?

Comment: Yes, you can have open socket as long as you wish.

Comment: So if I take the example from http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html
Example: 17.2.2.

and just wrap it in a while 1: loop, then everytime I connect to it from my python code, send it a command, close the connection. The server will just open up the same socket again waiting to get another command?

Is this fine?